# Basement outlets don't work - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: electrical

Several outlets in the basement bedroom do not seem to work. The same thing with the overhead light. However some other outlets in the same room which are mounted at the top of the wall instead of the bottom actually do work. The circuit breaker is not tripped.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot or do I have to call an electrician? I don't remember there being anything in the home inspection report saying that these don't work however this is the first time I've tried to use them and they're not outputting any power.

Here are some photos of the circuit breaker and one of the outlets. In case you're wondering where the light is coming from it's from the one outlet that does work near the ceiling:
[image]
[image]

Adding some things from my home inspection report:

> **OPERATION OF GFCI & AFCI (GROUND FAULT & ARC FAULT CIRCUIT INTERRUPTERS) [Inspected] PLEASE BE AWARE** -- Recommended upgrade --
>   GFCI's (Ground Fault Circuit Interrupters) were not required, or were
>   required in fewer locations than current standards would require, when
>   this house was built. Where not already present, retrofitting GFCI
>   outlets to replace any outlets lacking ground fault protection at
>   appropriate locations would be a worthwhile and relatively inexpensive
>   upgrade to increase safety and bring up to current standards
>   (Currently GFCI's are not present at: small appliance outlets at the
>   kitchen counters; bathroom outlets; unfinished basement outlets;
>   garage outlets; exterior outlets).

[image]

Comment: Look for GFCI outlets that are tripped.  They could be anywhere.

Comment: @Tyson thank you. That was a good thought but I just checked and I don't see any at all.

Comment: Did you look literally everywhere?  Even places you don't realize are off?  I'm being persistent because part of my day job is talking to customers at an electrical contractors office.  I talk people thru this daily.  If I were setting odds I'd say 98% chance you haven't found the tripped GFCI to a 2% chance there is another problem.   There's a second chapter if you find a GFCI that won't reset, that probably means there is yet another tripped GFCI.

Comment: @Tyson I thought I did but I guess after reading that I'm gonna go check again thanks

Comment: @Tyson ok yea I am 100% sure now. I don't have any of those types of outlets in the whole house.

Comment: How old is the construction? for example do you know approx what year it was built?  Do some of your circuit breakers have a "test" button?   Did the home inspection you mentioned list GFCI'?  Another tip, many residential circuit breakers models still look "on" when they are tripped, usually you can find a tripped breaker with just a fingertip touch, tripped breakers the handle is loose .. If you find one of those then you mustvflip it to the full Off position first, THEN back to on.

Comment: Outdoor gfci? Garage? (Can you tell that I want @Tyson to be right?)

Comment: @Tyson it's 67 years old; 1950. Nope, no test buttons. I did notice the same exact situation in the second quasi-bedroom in the basement where the overhead light which is of the same design does not work and the floor outlets do not work and there's one in the wall at the ceiling that does work. I'm about to take your other advice and I will also review the home inspection report. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tyson OK I checked the circuit breaker turned everything off and back on and I did not have an effect. I'm about to upload a photo of the circuit breaker and of the outlets.

Comment: It's possible you have a problem you'll likely need to either find a friend with experience or call an electrician to conquer.  Since you mentioned the home IU inspection report tho, it tells me you recently purchased the house.  In that case you should have GFCI's somewhere.  The lender, insurance company, or both would have insisted.  and the home inspection report should have noted the absence of GFCI's in required locations.

Comment: @Tyson I did purchase last year about 10 months ago. They had a electrician come out for something completely unrelated but aside from that unrelated thing where they were getting rid of a broken outlet in my sunroom it didn't say that there were any electrical problems. I live in Maryland I'm not sure if maybe the rules are different here about the GFCI

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I don't see any like that outside.

Comment: Call an electrician, while they are there have him/her install GFCI's in bathrooms, kitchen, garage, outdoor and basement outlets.  It's been required by code in all states for many years.  If you somehow don't have any get them ASAP.  The inspection report should say you don't have them.

Comment: @Tyson thank you I will. I haven't found the inspection report yet but you're probably right.

Comment: @Tyson Found the inspection report. They had a lot to say about the electrical system. It lists places where the GFCI doesn't exist and says it's "not required" but "recommended" but despite the way they set it up... as a list of places without it.. they list every single place there's outlets in my home. I don't think the other info is helpful but I will include everything that didn't get fixed prior to purchase in the question.

Comment: @Hack-R No, it doesn't "...list every single place there's outlets...".  Only the wet locations.  It's not that things needed to be or weren't "...fixed prior to purchase..." (you weren't duped, deceived, or got less than you paid for) because sellers aren't req'd to upgrade electrical prior to sale.  Just clarifying you weren't "wronged"; nor is problem as bad as you stated in "comments".

Comment: In basements that have been flooded (especially w/ salt water), outlets along the baseboard might be abandoned and made redundant with outlets higher up on the walls.  Given all info. stated, this is a mystery best suited for an electrician.

Comment: @JamesOlson I think you're confused. I was saying that the list of places where there is not GFCI includes all my outlets. There are 0 GFCI outlets on my property. I don't care at all that there are 0 GFCI outlets, but I was talking to Tyson about them. Regarding things fixed prior to purchase - I was stating that I'm not putting in the question parts of the home inspection report that were fixed because there would be no point in that. The problem is exactly as described - outlets in the locations I specified don't work. GFCI is not my problem. It sounds like you must've misread something.

Comment: @Tyson The electricians just left. The problem was that the treadmill I was using to test the power outlets had to power switches whereas I knew of just one, and the bulbs in the ceiling were dead. Power works fine. Doh! I knew I should've learned to use the multimeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electricians just left. The problem was that the treadmill I was using to test the power outlets had 2 power switches whereas I knew of just one, and the bulbs in the ceiling were dead. Power works fine. Doh!

I knew I should've learned to use the multimeter.

Comment: This is why when you call technical support, the first three questions are: "*Is it plugged in?*", "*Is it turned on?*", "*Are you sure?*".